# Getting 4 exceptions/errors in the editor but can't figure what are they ? And how to repair them?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image: Exceptions/Errors]

In the Hierarchy I have a capsule as player with a script attached to it :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 10.0f;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float translatioin = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * speed;
        float straffe = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed;
        translatioin *= Time.deltaTime;
        straffe *= Time.deltaTime;

        transform.Translate(straffe, 0, translatioin);
    }
}
```

And there is a camera child of the player with this script attached :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerCameraMouseLook : MonoBehaviour
{
    Vector2 mouseLook;
    Vector2 smoothV;

    public float sensitivity = 5.0f;
    public float smoothing = 2.0f;

    private GameObject player;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        player = this.transform.parent.gameObject;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        var md = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse X"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse Y"));

        md = Vector2.Scale(md, new Vector2(sensitivity * smoothing, sensitivity * smoothing));
        smoothV.x = Mathf.Lerp(smoothV.x, md.x, 1f / smoothing);
        smoothV.y = Mathf.Lerp(smoothV.y, md.y, 1f / smoothing);
        mouseLook += smoothV;

        mouseLook.y = Mathf.Clamp(mouseLook.y, -90f, 90f);

        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(-mouseLook.y, Vector3.right);
        player.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(mouseLook.x, Vector3.up);
    }
}
```

When I click on one of the errors in the editor it's not showing to what script it belong to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a duplicate of the post [Why do I keep getting two exceptions: Slope Limit must be smaller than 90 degrees and offset must be less?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/155170/121653) on the gamedev stackexchange. I've pasted [the accepted answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/155173/121653) by [DMGregory](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/39518/dmgregory) below for reference:

> Try this:
>
> Take your player avatar object that you want to scale down and break
>   it into two parts:
>
> 1. A top-level container object you can think of as your "logical avatar." This object should have its scale set to (1, 1, 1). It will
>      be used for any gameplay behaviours the avatar needs to interact with,
>      including:
>
>    - hosting the character controller component
>    - being the target of any scripts that need to reference the player avatar
> 2. A child "visual" object that contains your character's mesh and any animation components it needs. You can scale this object however you
>      want without interfering with the physics & gameplay logic handled
>      higher up at its parent.
>
> Separating the gameplay & visual parts of your objects can give you a
>   lot more flexibility to iterate with appearances, feedback, and scales
>   without mucking up your physics & play logic.